# What is the probability a random number I select is a perfect square

Tags: probability, number-theory

I have been thinking about this problem

Yes, let's simplify the problem by assuming the set of only positive integers $Z$
I know if I take a range of numbers say $1$  to  $10$ , there are only three perfect square existing here; which are $1$ , $4$ and $9$ 
So the probability is $3/10$ 
If I increase my range the probability becomes lesser, so I can conclude there are more imperfect-square numbers than perfect squares.

My question
Is there any fixed value assign to this, can I know the minimum and maximum value of this probability

Comment: You need to specify more things. Whats a perfect square? Simply x s.t. sqrt(x) is an integer again? What is the probability distribution on lN ? Or are we considering {1, ..., n}?

Comment: A perfect square.  X ( a positive integer ) , x s.t. sqrt(X) is a positive integer again.     we are considering {1,2,3,.…........,n}, considering all the set of positive integer again

Comment: If $n$ tends to $\infty$ , the probability that a random number in the range $[1,n]$ is a perfect square, tends to $0$. So , if we allow the random number to be any positive integer, the probability is $0$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability  that a uniformly chosen integer in $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ is a perfect square is given by  $$p_n={\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor\over n}\ ,$$ because there are exactly $\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$ perfect squares in $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$. As
$$\sqrt{n}-1<\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor\leq\sqrt{n}$$
we therefore can say that
$${1\over\sqrt{n}}-{1\over n}<p_n\leq{1\over\sqrt{n}}\ ,$$
which proves that $\lim_{n\to\infty} p_n=0$.

Comment: Nice, thanks just understood it, the probability is not zero but tends to it as n approach inf